# Where can I download a fully patched set of bash source to resolve the "shellshock" exploit

Tags: bash

After downloading bash-4.3 and applying patches 1 through 25 (from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash), the compiled version of bash still suffers from two potential exploits (as described in the following article: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223)

My question is this: does anyone known where I can download the remaining patches or a fully patched set of source from a reputable site?

Here are the relevant snippets from the linked article:

```
The versions with only the original CVE-2014-6271 fix applied 
produce the following output:

$ env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test"
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x()'
test
```

---

```
The fix for CVE-2014-7169 ensures that the system is protected from the file 
creation issue. To test if your version of Bash is vulnerable to CVE-2014-7169,
run the following command:

$ cd /tmp; rm -f /tmp/echo; env 'x=() { (a)=>\' bash -c "echo date"; cat /tmp/echo
bash: x: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `='
bash: x: line 1: `'
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
Fri Sep 26 11:49:58 GMT 2014

If your system is vulnerable, the time and date information will be output on the
screen and a file called /tmp/echo will be created.

If your system is not vulnerable, you will see output similar to:

$ cd /tmp; rm -f /tmp/echo; env 'x=() { (a)=>\' bash -c "echo date"; cat /tmp/echo
date
cat: /tmp/echo: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patches against CVE-2014-7169 were originally posted here:
http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2014/09/26/1

Later on they were pushed to the official GNU ftp site: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/

They need to be applied on top of the patches against CVE-2014-6271

Answer (score 0):

What's your OS?  I just followed the instructions here for an EOL Ubuntu system and they worked well: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245682&p=13128872#post13128872

which was adapted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-and-how-do-i-fix-it/528171#528171

I think the 3.2 version is for 32-bit, and 4.3 is 64-bit, trying to confirm that now...

Comment: A few different OS's: an older Solaris system, and an older AIX box as well. Did you try the additional exploit examples from the article that I linked? The version I built passes the exploit test in your linked article, but fails the others. My understanding is that the first patch attempt made was insufficient.

Comment: no you're right, this doesn't resolve those other exploits on the older system :(  I should delete my answer, sorry.

Comment: Hey, no problem. We're all just trying to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian and it's derivatives (Ubuntu/Mint) users, the fixed Bash is already in the repos. To fix it, just type `apt-get update && apt-get install --only-upgrade bash`.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 20, the fixed version of the bash is in the repositories as well.